# Is there a Knockoutjs equivalent of Wpf/Silverlight notifyPropertyChanged method?

Tags: javascript, wpf, silverlight, mvvm, knockout.js

Is there a Knockoutjs equivalent of Wpf/Silverlight `notifyPropertyChanged` method? How can I  manually invoke a property update in the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valueHasMutated` is what you're looking for:

```
viewModel.name.valueHasMutated();
```